# $AC^T = \det(A)I$

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant, laplace-expansion

Let A = $\begin{bmatrix}    a_{11} & a_{12}  & \dots & a_{1n} \\ a_{21} & a_{22}  & \dots & a_{2n}  \\ \vdots & \vdots  & \ddots & \vdots \\ a_{n1} & a_{n2} &
\dots & a_{nn} \end{bmatrix}$ 
and the matrix of cofactors of $A$ is 
$$C=\begin{bmatrix}    C_{11} & C_{12}  & \dots & C_{1n} \\ C_{21} & C_{22}  & \dots & C_{2n}  \\ \vdots & \vdots  & \ddots & \vdots \\ C_{n1} & C_{n2} &
\dots & C_{nn} \end{bmatrix}.
$$
I try to understand why $AC^T = \det(A)I$ necessarily.

Why is it that $a_{11}C_{21} + a_{12}C_{22} + \dots + a_{1n}C_{2n} = 0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression
$$
\color{red}{a_{11}}C_{21} + \color{red}{a_{12}}C_{22} + \dots + \color{red}{a_{1n}}C_{2n}
$$
is the [Laplace expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_expansion) along the second row of
$$
\begin{vmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12}  & \dots & a_{1n} \\ \color{red}{a_{11}} & \color{red}{a_{12}}  & \color{red}\dots & \color{red}{a_{1n}} \\ a_{31} & a_{32} & \dots & a_{3n} \\ \vdots & \vdots  & \ddots & \vdots \\ a_{n1} & a_{n2} &
\dots & a_{nn}
\end{vmatrix}=\color{red}{a_{11}}C_{21} + \color{red}{a_{12}}C_{22} + \dots + \color{red}{a_{1n}}C_{2n}=0.
$$

Edit: take the matrix $A$ and do the determinant expansion along the second row
$$
\begin{vmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12}  & \dots & a_{1n} \\ \color{blue}{a_{21}} & \color{blue}{a_{22}}  & \color{blue}\dots & \color{blue}{a_{2n}}  \\ a_{31} & a_{32} & \dots & a_{3n} \\ \vdots & \vdots  & \ddots & \vdots \\ a_{n1} & a_{n2} & \dots & a_{nn}
\end{vmatrix}=\color{blue}{a_{21}}C_{21} + \color{blue}{a_{22}}C_{22} + \dots + \color{blue}{a_{2n}}C_{2n}.
$$
Observe that the blue elements are not used to build $C_{2j}$. If we replace the blue elements with the red elements above we get exactly what we need.

Comment: Where did that determinant come from? Why do the first two rows suddenly become the same? Sorry I'm slow, don't see the jump. I got the same answer from the book.

Comment: @KidCudi Yes, it may take time to understand. The determinant expansion of a matrix is the sum of the element${}_{ij}\cdot$the cofactor${}_{ij}$. The expression has the same structure as the determinant expansion along the second row. The red elements must be the elements of the row and the cofactors are the same as for the matrix $A$ for the same row. Observe that the second row is not used when building the cofactors. Try to do the expanstion for this matrix yourself.

Comment: @KidCudi I have edited the answer, hopefully it is clearer now.

Comment: I kinda get the idea. I know that B the matrix with repeated rows has determinant 0. Are you saying  A can be expanded somehow to include B?

Comment: @KidCudi I am saying that the expression in question $a_{11}C_{21}+\ldots$ is the determinant expansion of $B$, which is zero. Then the expression is also zero.

Comment: I have added a $3$-rd row to your two matrices to make the pattern behind the \vdots clearer.

Comment: @darijgrinberg Thank you, it was nice of you.